# Removing item from list causes the list to become NoneType

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I imagine there is a simple solution that I am overlooking. Better that than a complicated one, right?

Simply put:

```
var = ['p', 's', 'c', 'x', 'd'].remove('d')
```

causes `var` to be of type `None`. What is going on here?

Comment: You're using `.remove` wrong?  Do you mean `.pop`?

Comment: No, pop is to remove an element at an certain place in the list, if I recall. I want to remove a specific element (such as 'd').

Comment: As a side note, many uses of `remove` (and `index` and other list-searching methods) are signs of a problem with the design. Maybe you should be using a `set`, or maybe you have or should have the index but aren't using it, etc. That's definitely not _always_ true, but it's worth thinking about.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`remove` doesn't return anything. It modifies the existing list in-place. No assignment needed.

Replace

```
var = ['p', 's', 'c', 'x', 'd'].remove('d')
```

with

```
var = ['p', 's', 'c', 'x', 'd']
var.remove('d')
```

Now `var` will have a value of `['p', 's', 'c', 'x']`.

Comment: Yep, that does it. I could have sword I tried this. Aw well, thanks for the answer! Will mark as answered in 11 minutes when it allows me to.

Comment: In general, almost _any_ method that mutates the object in Python returns `None`, or at least something other than `self`. (The exceptions are mostly special cases, like `__iadd__`, or domain-specific methods from frameworks that have their own different idioms.)

Comment: Actually in my case even that returns none

Comment: @user32882 might be worth composing a [mcve] and posting a new question, then

Comment: I realized I was making the same dumb mistake as the OP. I slapped myself across the forehead and all is well now.

Answer (score 3):

`remove` mutates the list in-place, and returns `None`. You have to put it in a variable, and then change that:

```
>>> var = ['p', 's', 'c', 'x', 'd']
>>> var.remove('d')   # Notice how it doesn't return anything.
>>> var
['p', 's', 'c', 'x']
```