# When iterating over a list and trying to remove('\n') the list returns None instead of the elements of the list

Tags: python, loops

Fairly new to Python but I'm trying to make a Scrabble anagram solver which will loop through a large text file and check for anagrams with a user given 7 letter rack. I'm working on the `is_anagram` function and using `sorted()` to make a list of the letters in the word in alphabetical order and then using a `if` statement to see if the sorted word from the dictionary is equal to the sorted rack of letters provided. Because the letters that are being searched come from a long list there is a `"\n"` in the list created from the words which makes it so they are not equal. I'm trying to set up the iteration so that it removes `'\n'` from the list before comparing it ,but for some reason it is returning the list as `None` instead of the list minus `'\n'`. Not sure why. Anyone can help? Code is below:

```
def is_anagram(word):
    scrabble_dict = open('sowpods.txt')
    for x in scrabble_dict:
        x = sorted(x)
        x = x.remove('\n')
        word = sorted(word)
        if word == x:
            print(word)
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766587/removing-item-from-list-causes-the-list-to-become-nonetype
Basically remove does not work like that. You don't need `x = x.remove('\n')` just `x.remove('\n')` is enough.

Comment: Answers the question! Thanks!

Comment: won't printing word after sorting it just print gibberish? Also isn't `word` the letters that the player has on his rack, and instead `x` is the actual word in the dictionary? If my understanding is correct, you want to save a copy of `x` before sorting, and if there is a match, print the saved copy so you actually get a word?  also using `if x in word` might be a better call, since it will allow you to check for dictionary entries that are smalled than `word`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after I figured out the issue with remove. I just set y = sorted(x) and used y as the variable and then had the function return x.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assign x again after removing the newline.

```
def is_anagram(word):
    scrabble_dict = open('sowpods.txt')
    for x in scrabble_dict:
        x = sorted(x)
        x.remove('\n')
        word = sorted(word)
        if word == x:
            print(word)
```