# remove() returns None when I try to remove a variable from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a part of a program that turns a statement into a question.

When I try to remove `x` it returns `None`. I want it to print the sentence with that item removed, what am I doing wrong?

```
def Ask(Question):
    Auxiliary = ("will", "might", "would", "do", "were", "are", "did")
    for x in Auxiliary:
        if x in Question:
            Question_l = Question.lower()
            Question_tk_l = word_tokenize(Question)
            Aux_Rem = Question_tk_l.remove(x)
            print (Aux_Rem)
```

Example for behaviour wanted:

```
"what we are doing in the woods"
```

should become

```
"what we doing in the woods"
```

I want to remove any auxiliary word from question.

Comment: By the way, don't modify lists while iterating on them, or you will get an exception

Comment: Do you want to remove _all_ instances, or just one at a time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing item from list causes the list to become nonetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766587/removing-item-from-list-causes-the-list-to-become-nonetype)

Answer (score 4):

That's correct behaviour. `remove` removes that element and doesn't return a value (i.e. returns `None`). You can use `pop` if you wish to access the removed element.

Comment: no i want to access the string now without that item in it. that's why i removed it shouldn't it print the Question without the Aux?

Answer (score 3):

`somelist.remove(x)` removes the first element it finds that equals `x` from `somelist`. It doesn't return the modified list. To print the modified list, simply print the list.

```
print(Question_tk_l)
```

If you want to turn it into a nice string, you should join it with space.

```
print(' '.join(Question_tk_l))
```

Comment: here i have this now def Ask(Question):
    Auxiliary = ("will","might","would","do","were","are","did")
    for x in Auxiliary:
        if x in Question:
            Question_l = Question.lower()
            Question_tk_l = word_tokenize(Question)
            Question_tk_l.remove(x)
            print(' '.join(Question_tk_l))
        else:
            print ("thingy")

Comment: and i got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    Ask("what you were doing")
  File "/media/pi/TRAVELDRIVE/Jarvis AI Code/Jarvis_Resourses/Jarvis_Functions.py", line 101, in Ask
    Question_tk_l.remove(x)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: As the error says, it's not in the list. You can't remove something that's not there.

Comment: Never Mind i got the results i wanted now but your answer definitely helped my get there thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You were very very nearly right. You dont need to create a new variable for the  modified list. You can just do:

```
def Ask(Question): 
    Auxiliary = ("will", "might", "would", "do", "were", "are", "did") 
    for x in Auxiliary: 
        if x in Question:
            Question_l = Question.lower() 
            Question_tk_l = word_tokenize(Question) 
            Question_tk_l.remove(x) 
            print (Question_tk_l)
```

So I got rid of the (Aux_Rem) variable and just modified the list then reprinted the list.