# Remove element from cell when cell contents is a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

Using the dataframe posted below, I need to remove element `0` from each cell in column `Var2` (each cell is a list), but only for rows where `Var1 > 0`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Var1': [1,0,3,1],
                   'Var2': [[0,8],[6,0],[1,3,0],[5,0,3]]
```

I tried this, but the output is not what I expected - it seems to remove all elements in the cell.

```
df['Var2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Var2'].remove(0) if x['Var1']>0 else  x['Var2'], axis = 1)
╔══════════════╗
║ Var1    Var2 ║
╠══════════════╣
║    1    None ║
║    0  [6, 0] ║
║    3    None ║
║    1    None ║
╚══════════════╝
```

The desired output is:

```
╔══════════════╗
║ Var1    Var2 ║
╠══════════════╣
║    1     [8] ║
║    0  [6, 0] ║
║    3  [1, 3] ║
║    1  [5, 3] ║
╚══════════════╝
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, I wonder whether this could be done without using `apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a list comprehension. Your code doesn't work because `list.remove` is an in-place operation which returns `None`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766587/removing-item-from-list-causes-the-list-to-become-nonetype) for more details.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Var1': [1,0,3,1],
                   'Var2': [[0,8],[6,0],[1,3,0],[5,0,3]]})

def remove_zero(x):
    return [i for i in x if i != 0]

df.loc[df['Var1'] > 0, 'Var2'] = df['Var2'].apply(remove_zero)

print(df)

   Var1    Var2
0     1     [8]
1     0  [6, 0]
2     3  [1, 3]
3     1  [5, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

`remove` working `inplace` (return `None`s), so need list comprehension with filtering:

```
f = lambda x: [y for y in x['Var2'] if y != 0] if x['Var1']>0 else x['Var2']
df['Var2'] = df.apply(f, axis = 1)
print (df)
   Var1    Var2
0     1     [8]
1     0  [6, 0]
2     3  [1, 3]
3     1  [5, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

inside `if` condition (Var1 not equal to zero) block find the index of 0 and remove it and return back to the list and save the result back.

```
print df.apply(lambda x: list(np.delete(x['Var2'],x['Var2'].index(0))) if x['Var1']!=0 else x['Var2'],axis=1)
```

Input:

```
   Var1       Var2
0     1     [0, 8]
1     0     [6, 0]
2     3  [1, 3, 0]
3     1  [5, 0, 3]
```

Output:

```
   Var1    Var2
0     1     [8]
1     0  [6, 0]
2     3  [1, 3]
3     1  [5, 3]
```