# Python: Remove element from list returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

According to this [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/remove) it should be easy to remove an element from a list. The example provided in the link works fine. In my use case I need a wrapper function that avoids the error from being returned if the passed list does not contain the element that should be removed.

This is the code that I've come up with:

```
def filterval(ls,val):
    if val in ls:
        return(ls.remove(val))
    else:
        return(ls)
```

Strangely though, this code returns None in the following situation:

```
print(filterval([1,2,3,4,5],2))
```

Interestingly if I define a list:

```
tlist = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and execute

```
print(filterval(tlist,2))
```

it still prints None, but printing tlist reveals that '2' has been removed successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing item from list causes the list to become nonetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766587/removing-item-from-list-causes-the-list-to-become-nonetype)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to change `filterval()` to:

```
def filterval(ls, val):
    if val in ls:
        ls.remove(val)
    return ls
```

The issue is that `list.remove()` returns `None`. If you want to get the list back from your function you should return that and not whatever is the result of `list.remove()`.

---

You could also use a comprehension or the `filter()` built-in (although for filtering out a single element `list.remove()` is more efficient):

```
def filterval(ls, val):
    return [x fox x in ls if x != val]


def filterval(ls, val):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x != val, ls))
```

This coding patterns are so common that you typically would not want to have an extra function for encapsulating this.
Also, the first form (with the comprehension) is deemed to be more *Pythonic*.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing wrong. `list.remove` returns `None`, so your function returns `None` too.

If you want to return the modified list, do it:

```
def filterval(List: list, data) -> list:
    if data in List:      # [You] Yo, List, do you have this element?
        ...               # [List] I sure do!
        List.remove(data) # [You] Please remove it then.
    else:                 # [List] Nope, I don't have it(
        ...               # [You] Okay then

    return List
```

Or "ask for forgiveness" instead of "asking for permission":

```
def filterval(List: list, data) -> list:
    try:                  # [You] Let me try this...
        List.remove(data) # [You] Hey, mate, please remove this element.
    except ValueError:    # [List] I can't, I don't even have this element, dude...
        ...               # [You] Oops, sorry, man, didn't know you were broke
    else:                 # [List] Yeah, sure!
        ...               # [You] Great, thanks!

    return List
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a hash table to remove an element:

```py
list(set(ls)-{val})
```

which is one more char than the call to `filterval(ls, val)` itself.
So if you still want a function, it becomes:

```py
def filterval(ls, val):
    return list(set(ls)-{val})
```

If you only want to iterate over your elements you could spare the `list()` call and use the set directly:

```py
for item in set(ls) - {val}:
    print (item)
```

You can pass multiple elements within the subtraction and add some more values using the union operator `|`:

```py
set(ls) - {val, vel, vil} | {vol, vul}
```

But you have to keep in mind that this will not allow for duplicate elements: `{'x'} | {'x'} = {'x'}` and not `{'x', 'x'}`