# using .remove seperately vs using it in tolist()

Tags: python, pandas

when I do this

```
    my_list = df.loc[df['ID']  == "9", ['ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4']].values.flatten().tolist()
```

I get the result

```
    my_list = ['-1','32','63','-1']
```

And then when I do my_list .remove('-1') I see

```
    my_list = ['32','63']
```

which is what I want to see .**However when I try to do .remove in single step like**

```
    my_list = df.loc[df['ID']  == "9",['ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4']].values.flatten().tolist().remove('-1')
```

then my_list is empty.

Why is this happening?

Comment: list remove is an inplace operation and returns `None` [Removing item from list causes the list to become NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26766587/15497888)

Answer (score 1):

Because `remove` does the operation in place, modifying the list itself.  It doesn't return anything.